# Рекурсия многомерных массивов php

Tags: php, массивы, рекурсия

В поисках решения своей проблемы наткнулся на вот такой код.

> Простой способ перебрать многомерный ассоциированный массив и получить
>   из него трубуемые элементы, например по ключу:

```
function recarray($ar, $searchfor) {
    static $result = array();

    foreach($ar as $k => $v) {
    if ($k == $searchfor) $result[] = $v;
        if (is_array($ar[$k]))  recarray($v, $searchfor);
    }
    return $result;
}

$tst = array (
  'bob' => 'Bob MEN',
  'google' => array (
      'somekey' => 'somevalue',
      'bob'     => 'big man'
  ),
  'martin' => array(
      'bob'     => array(
      'friend' => true,
      'age'    => 100500),
      'cat'     => 'animal'
  )
);

$result = recarray($tst, 'bob');

print_r($result);
```

> Результатом работы скриптика будет:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Bob MEN
    [1] => big man
    [2] => Array
        (
            [friend] => 1
            [age] => 100500
        )

)
```

Все неплохо, но моя проблема такова, что если я добавляю ещё одно измерение массива (3), то функция добавит результат в первое (1) измерение.

```
$tst = array('bob'    => 'Bob MEN',
             'google' => array('somekey' => 'somevalue',
                               'bob'     => 'big man'),
             'martin' => array('bob'     => array('friend' => true,
                                                  'age'    => 100500),
                                            'cat'     => 'animal',
                                            'sad'     => array('rkg' => 'lol',
                                                               'bob' => 'nono   '))
);

$result = recarray($tst, 'bob');
```

**Результат:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Bob MEN
    [1] => big man
    [2] => Array
        (
            [friend] => 1
            [age] => 100500
        )

    [3] => nono
)
```

Как сделать, что-бы результат был таков, как он ожидается, т.е. если измерение исходного массива 3/4/5...n, то и результирующий массив будет иметь столько же вложений, а результаты будут в своих измерениях?

Comment: Вы в первом примере вытащили `big man` из вложенного массива `google` на 1 уровень выше и сказали, что это правильно. А во втором примере не хотите что бы значения поднимались выше. И если значение должно остаться на своем уровне вложенности, то как должна выглядеть структура массивов ведущая к нему

Comment: Я имею ввиду, что если искомый элемент находится во вложенном массиве - что бы он и выводился во вложенном (в новом массиве)

Comment: Но тогда и `big man` должен быть в отдельном массиве ?

Comment: Да! Но как реализовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если имена ключей по пути к найденному элементу сохранять не надо, а просто нумеровать их, то так:

```
function recarray($ar, $searchfor) {
    $result = array();

    foreach($ar as $k => $v) {
    if ($k == $searchfor) $result[] = $v;
    else if (is_array($ar[$k]))
     {
      $ret=recarray($v, $searchfor);
      if(count($ret)) $result[]=$ret;
     }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Для полного сохранения структуры массива с именами ключей надо использовать `$result[$k]` в обоих точках, где происходит добавление элементов в результирующий массив.

Comment: Из-за имен ключей и возникла вся проблема. Как их сохранить?

Comment: Да нет. я сделал `$result` не static что бы на каждом уровне иерархии он был свой и как видите проверяю что вернули непустой массив. Имена ключей ... вместо `$result[]=` использовать `$result[$k]=`

Comment: Спасибо, друг, очень выручил. Надеюсь поможешь с будущими вопросами)

Comment: @tekken Обрати внимание, я только что добавил `else` перед `if(is_array())` потому как если имя совпало мы уже весь нижележащий массив скопировали и проходить по нему рекурсией не надо.

Comment: Т.е. если имя совпало с ключем массива, то по нему уже проходить не будет. А что, если в этом массиве также есть искомый ключ?

Comment: Но мы же уже целиком весь такой массив в результат скопировали, значит все что в нем уже есть так и останется.

Comment: Майк, а можно ЛС? Есть пару вопросов по этой же теме. treez[.]ua[@]gmail[.]com