# Задача коммивояжера на php (Поиск кратчайшего маршрута)

Tags: php, массивы

Задача:
Есть ряд точек с расстоянием и временем прибытия. Не между всеми точками есть прямая связь. Зная начальный и конечный пункт, нужно найти кратчайший путь (или время).

Таблица, без особых излишеств, выглядит так:

```
id  city_1  city_2  distance_km     time_mins
1     A       B          80            40
2     A       C          110           55
3     A       E          330           240
4     B       F          340           230
5     C       D          60            20
6     C       E          205           80
7     D       F          192           110
8     E       F          80            40
```

Реализацию задумал такую:

- Функции на вход подается начальная и конечная точка.
- По начальной точке делается запрос в базу, где выбираются все уникальные значения для полей `city_1` и `city_2` для входной точки (отсортировано по нарастающей).
- Получившийся массив пускаем через `foreach`, и для каждой точки в выборке запускаем рекурсивно эту же функцию, параллельно сохраняя эти точки в возвратный массив.

На момент написания сего эпоса недокод выглядит так (пока запрос без сортировки):

```
try {
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=voyage", "root", "");
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}catch (PDOException $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

function getTree($start, $end){
    global $dbh;
    $query = "(SELECT city_1 AS $start FROM distances WHERE city_2='{$start}') UNION (SELECT city_2 FROM distances WHERE city_1='{$start}')";
    $st = $dbh->query($query);
    $res = $st->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $tree = array();
    foreach ($res as $k => $v) {
        if($k == $end)
            $tree[] = $v;
        elseif(is_array($res[$k])){
            $ret=getTree($v, $end);
            if(count($ret))
                $tree[] = $ret;
        }
    }
    return $tree;
}
```

Запустив этот код сейчас, получается такое:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [A] => B
        )

)
```

Наполнение массива подсказали [отсюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/481945/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B2-php).
По задумке, я должен получить массив от начальной точки до всех возможных концов (`$end`). Далее, одну из ветвей массива вида `$tree['A']['C']['D']['F']`, ключи которых я бы в будущем разобрал и по которым вывел варианты маршрута.
А теперь о трудностях:

1. Этот метод наполнения возвратного массива так и не смог адаптировать под свои нужды.
2. Если, например, в очередной итерации я подам ключ `'С'`, надо отфильтровать родительский ключ, иначе будет бесконечность. Я понимаю, что в нужный момент нужно добавить условие, что бы пропустить итерацию при помощи `continue`. Но как обратится к родительскому ключу?
3. Каким образом перебрать каждую ветку возвращаемого массива, именно ключи (пример ветки ниже).

Т.е, запустив код `getTree('A', 'F');`, я ожидаю получить такие результаты (без сортировки):

```
Array
(
    [B] => F
    [C] => Array
        (
            [D] => F
            [E] => F
        )

    [E] => F
)
```

Comment: Сначала стоит прочитать https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%94%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%8B. У меня ощущение, что в массив можно вести с такой же структурой, как таблица. Без вложенностей. Тут же в нем можно отмечать какие узлы вы уже посещали

Comment: С алгоритмом Дейстры я знаком. А на счет всей таблицы в массиве. А если размер таблицы громаден? Это не скажется на производительности?

Comment: Ну смотря на сколько громаден. И повторная выборка из базы записей которые были на других шагах алгоритма - это точно на производительности скажется. И проблема номер один, да, вы правы,  не зациклится, но не зациклится мы можем только помня через какие пары точек мы уже проходили

Comment: Я тут прикинул ... вам при любом поиске всегда придется проходить по всей маршрутной сети. Так что таблицу полюбому всю грузить в память. Видимо надо вводить понятия максимально возможных расстояний, что бы вовремя обрубать совершенно безнадежные маршруты. Если сеть действительно большая и задача не просто из академического интереса, то возможно стоит подумать о других СУБД

Comment: Ну пока это чисто академический интерес. В таком случае, в какую сторону двигаться? Я по Ваших рекомендациях попробую реализовать код

Comment: Ну на вскидку один большой массив. в нем ключи - узлы графа под ключем массив точек до которых напрямую можно добраться. начинаем с 'A', грузим в массив $M['A']['B']=80, так же AC AE. начинаем ... можно рекурсию, а можно и так для начала попробовать. В общем берем B из записи AB и грузим в этот же массив [B][F]. [B][A] видимо то же грузим. Самое главное что в какой то момент будет опять вызвана функция "загрузи все A", она  увидит, что в массиве уже есть записи A, значит тут мы уже были и она тут же завершается.

Comment: Почитал еще Дейкстру ... Вот прямо по нему и предлагаю грузить в массив список вершин и сразу расставлять их цены (именно вершин) и обязательно у каждой вершины признак полной ее обработки, что бы в нее не пытаться больше возвращаться

Comment: Когда одну вершину закончили считать, пробегаемся по массиву сначала, находим необработанную вершину - начинаем считать ее паралельно подгружая недостающее

Comment: Увидев в заголовке задача коммивояжера решил написать, что сама задача решается или полным перебором или жадным алгоритмов: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Задача_коммивояжёра#.D0.9F.D1.80.D0.BE.D1.81.D1.82.D0.B5.D0.B9.D1.88.D0.B8.D0.B5 То есть расчёт маршрута с большим количеством вершин может занять много времени.

Answer (score 3):

Вы меня слишком заинтриговали задачей, пришлось ее решить :) Правда при наличии информации в базе мне лениво делать на php и я решил делать целиком в MySQL. Заодно научился процедуры создавать. Сделал на скорую руку, для реальной работы надо немного пересмотреть политику создания новых записей в таблице запросов и удаления их при изменениях в таблице дистанций. Но обо всем по порядку ...

Структура базы:

```
create table distances(  /* Ваша таблица дистанций */
 city_1 varchar(4) not null, city_2 varchar(4) not null,
 dist_km int not null, time_mins int not null,
 primary key(city_1,city_2)
);
insert into distances(city_1,city_2,dist_km,time_mins) values
('A','B',80,40),('A','C',110,55),('A','E',330,240),('B','F',340,230),
('C','D',60,20),('C','E',205,80),('D','F',192,110),('E','F',80,40),('X','A',400,320);

create table dquery(  /* Таблица запросов. При каждом поиске маршрута сюда добавляется запись */
/* При реальной эксплуатации стоит добавлять запись, только если еще не делали поиск для данной точки отправления и метрики*/
/* И выбирать существующую - если делали */
/* при изменениях в таблице дистанций - удалять все поиски */
 qid int not null auto_increment,
 city varchar(4) not null,  /* Маршруты из этого города */
 mtype char(1) default 'D' not null, /* Метрика: D - Дистанции, T - время в пути*/
 primary key(qid)
);

create table vertex(  /* Все узлы, до которых можно добраться из пункта запроса*/
 qid int not null,           /* ID запроса */
 vcity varchar(4) not null,  /* Город назначения */
 metric int,                 /* Лучшая метрика */
 closed char(1) default 'N' not null, /* Узел обработан */
 route varchar(1000),        /* Лучший маршрут */
 primary key (qid,vcity)
);
```

Процедура поиска маршрутов по [алгоритму Дейкстры](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%94%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%8B):

```
drop procedure if exists deykstra;
delimiter $$
create procedure deykstra(p_city varchar(4),p_type char(1))
/* Параметры: город для которого ищем маршруты, тип метрики (расстояние/время) */
begin
 declare m_qid int;             /* Текущий запрос */
 declare m_city varchar(4);     /* Город проверяемого узла */
 declare m_metric int;          /* Текущая метрика от пункта A до текущего узла */
 declare m_route varchar(1000); /* Маршрут от пункта А до текущего узла */
 declare numrows int;           /* кол-во записей (флаг завершения работы */

 insert into dquery(city,mtype) values(p_city,p_type); /* Вставляем запись запроса */
 SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() into m_qid; /* Сохраняем ее ID */
-- Вставляем запись для начального узла
 insert into vertex values(m_qid,p_city,0,'N',p_city);

 main: LOOP /* Главный и единственный цикл */
  select vcity, metric, route, count(1)  /* Получаем очередной рабочий узел */
    into m_city,m_metric,m_route,numrows
    from vertex
   where qid=m_qid and closed='N' limit 1;

  IF numrows=0 THEN /* Если узлов больше нет - завершаем работу */
   LEAVE main;
  END IF;

  /* Вставляем вновь обнаруженные узлы и меняем метрику и маршрут у существующих узлов */
  /* с большей метрикой, чем найденная */
  insert into vertex(qid,vcity,metric,route)
  select m_qid,A.city,A.metric,concat(m_route,',',A.city)  /* К маршруту до текущего узла, добавляем следующий город */
    from
    (select if(city_1=m_city,city_2,city_1) city,
            if(p_type='D',dist_km,time_mins)+m_metric metric /* Метрика до текущего узла + метрика из него до следующего */
       from distances
      where (city_1=m_city or city_2=m_city)
    ) A
   where not exists(
      select 1 from vertex V  /* только записи для которых нет уже известной, лучшей метрики */
       where V.qid=m_qid and V.vcity=A.city and V.metric<=A.metric
     )
      on duplicate key update
         metric=A.metric,route=concat(m_route,',',A.city);

  /* Помечаем текущий узел пройденным */
  update vertex set closed='Y' where qid=m_qid and vcity=m_city;
 END LOOP main;

 select * from vertex where qid=m_qid; /* Возвращаем набор всех найденных узлов */
end$$
```

Так как для поиска оптимального маршрута необходимо пройти все узлы сети и сохранить метрики для всех пройденных узлов, нет никакого смысла искать  маршрут из пункта A в пункт Б. Гораздо удобнее сохранить все оптимальные маршруты из пункта А во все достижимые пункты. И потом из этой таблички выбирать маршруты по мере надобности.

Алгоритм получился даже проще, чем я ожидал изначально. Никаких рекурсий и сложных структур. Один цикл, выбирающий еще не обработанный узел из таблицы узлов и добавляющий в нее же все вновь найденные. Прошли узел, поставили отметку, что бы не возвращаться более к нему. Если реализовывать на php, то вместо моей таблицы `vertex` вам понадобится массив записей с аналогичной структурой, разве что qid можно будет убрать.

Результаты работы:

```
Из пункта A с метрикой "дистанция":
mysql> call deykstra('A','D');
+-----+-------+--------+--------+---------+
| qid | vcity | metric | closed | route   |
+-----+-------+--------+--------+---------+
|   8 | A     |      0 | Y      | A       |
|   8 | B     |     80 | Y      | A,B     |
|   8 | C     |    110 | Y      | A,C     |
|   8 | D     |    170 | Y      | A,C,D   |
|   8 | E     |    315 | Y      | A,C,E   |
|   8 | F     |    362 | Y      | A,C,D,F |
|   8 | X     |    400 | Y      | A,X     |
+-----+-------+--------+--------+---------+

Из пункта A с метрикой "время":
mysql> call deykstra('A','T');
+-----+-------+--------+--------+---------+
| qid | vcity | metric | closed | route   |
+-----+-------+--------+--------+---------+
|  10 | A     |      0 | Y      | A       |
|  10 | B     |     40 | Y      | A,B     |
|  10 | C     |     55 | Y      | A,C     |
|  10 | D     |     75 | Y      | A,C,D   |
|  10 | E     |    135 | Y      | A,C,E   |
|  10 | F     |    175 | Y      | A,C,E,F |
|  10 | X     |    320 | Y      | A,X     |
+-----+-------+--------+--------+---------+
```

А для решения задачи поиска всех путей на php думаю стоит делать не сильно вложенный массив, а например массив с ключами в виде путей, как у меня в таблицах получились, через запятую или другой разделитель. Тогда идя рекурсией, вы будете видеть всегда пройденный маршрут и не возвращаться в точки, в которых уже были, просто проверив наличие точки в текущем пути.

Код на PHP:

```
<?php
$input=array(array("city_1"=>'A',"city_2"=>'B',"distance_km"=>80,"time_mins"=>40),array("city_1"=>'A',"city_2"=>'C',"distance_km"=>110,"time_mins"=>55),array("city_1"=>'A',"city_2"=>'E',"distance_km"=>330,"time_mins"=>240),array("city_1"=>'B',"city_2"=>'F',"distance_km"=>340,"time_mins"=>230),array("city_1"=>'C',"city_2"=>'D',"distance_km"=>60,"time_mins"=>20),array("city_1"=>'C',"city_2"=>'E',"distance_km"=>205,"time_mins"=>80),
array("city_1"=>'D',"city_2"=>'F',"distance_km"=>192,"time_mins"=>110),
array("city_1"=>'E',"city_2"=>'F',"distance_km"=>80,"time_mins"=>40));

$dist=array();
foreach($input as $node)
{ // Строим массив дистанций для быстрого поиска [A][B]=80; [B][A]=80;
 $dist[$node['city_1']][$node['city_2']]=$node['distance_km'];
 $dist[$node['city_2']][$node['city_1']]=$node['distance_km'];
}
$result=Deykstra($dist,'A');
print "Route from A to F ".$result['F']['route']." distance ".$result['F']['metric']."\n";

function Deykstra($dist,$from)
{
 $M=array(array("vert"=>$from, "metric"=>0, "route"=>$from)); // Массив вершин с стартовой вершиной
 $S=array($from=>0); // Массив номеров элементов в массиве вершин по кодам городов
 for($i=0;$i<count($M);$i++) // Перебираем все вершины
  {
   // Данные проверяемой вершины Код, Маршрут, Метрика
   $v1=$M[$i]['vert']; $route=$M[$i]['route']; $metric=$M[$i]['metric'];
   foreach($dist[$M[$i]['vert']] as $v2=>$m2)
    { // Перебираем все вершины до которых можно добраться напрямую
     if(!array_key_exists($v2,$S)) // Вершина назначения еще не встречалась
      {
       $S[$v2]=count($M); // Добавляем индекс по коду
       $M[]=array("vert"=>$v2, "metric"=>($metric+$m2), "route"=>"$route/$v2"); // И саму вершину
      } else
      { // Вершина уже встречалась, пересчитываем метрику, если необходимо
       $ind=$S[$v2];
       if($M[$ind]['metric']>($metric+$m2)) // Метрика вершины больше текущей
        { // обновляем метрику и маршрут до вершины
         $M[$ind]['metric']=$metric+$m2;
         $M[$ind]['route']="$route/$v2";
        }
      }
    }
  }
 // Из массива по номерам, делаем по именам городов
 foreach($S as $key=>$ind) $S[$key]=$M[$ind];
 return $S;
}
```

Comment: Кстати не понял на примере точек A->F. Согласно алгоритму Дейкстры, если берем за начало точку А, то ищем от нее вершину с наименьшим расстоянием. Таковой является вершина В (80 км). От нее беру последующий отсчет, а это единственная точка F (340 км), что в сумме дает 420 км. По Вашему же алгоритму, если пройти через точки A->C->D->F, то общее расстояние будет равно 362 км. Что я упустил?

Comment: @tekken Вы не правильно поняли Дейкстру, он не идет по наименьшему ребру. он по очереди от данной вершины идет по всем ребрам, без рекурсии, не углубляясь, и стоимость ребра пишет в стоимость вершины, в случае, если она меньше, чем в данный момент записана в вершине. Таким образом после обработки вершины A в вершинах B,C,E просто записаны значения 80,110,330. Далее просто берем следующую известную там вершину, например B и идем из нее во все и в них пишем ее 80+вес ребра. В F 340+80=420. хотя таким образом по другим ребрам доходим опять до F, но с меньшей текущей стоимостью.

Comment: @tekken В MySQL мою модель соберите и в процедуру вставьте `select * from vertex where qid=m_qid;` внутрь цикла, после update. По идее увидите состояние таблицы вершин после каждой итерации алгоритма и станет понятнее

Comment: @tekken Вот, смотрите я сделал для вершины A: http://pastebin.com/B3D6dwL6  смотрите на колонку `closed` алгоритм обрабатывал ту вершину у которой было 'N' и стало 'Y'. И видно как меняются веса и маршруты у остальных вершин. Собственно вес вершины в таблице - это сумма весов по указанному у нее маршруту

Comment: @tekken В консоли - это в утилите mysql ? В гугле этот номер ошибки укажи, там есть всякие решения и конкретно процедур они не касаются. А вообще пока я это делал я просто эти запросы гонял без всякой процедуры просто по очереди, так сказать руками цикл выполнял. И вместо переменных, что в процедуре объявлены, использовал обычные с @

Comment: Mike, у меня уже мозг кипит) Если не сильно затруднит, покажи пример реализации на php, или хотя бы псевдокод накидай, а то я уже хз как это делать..

Comment: @tekken Сделал. собственно полная копия того что на sql было

Comment: Спасибо, друг! Чуть позже выложу пример реализации с использованием SPL, который подсмотрел на другом ресурсе.

Answer (score 1):

Дошел до того, что глядя на код, вроде все должно работать, но на самом деле вот так:
На вход функции подаю 2 точки, и обе начинаю проверять. Если при первом вызове одна из точек найдена (`$point1/$point2`), то она считается началом (записываем результат в массив), а другая (`$point2/$point1`) соответственно концом (записываю как `$nextPoint` и `$finishPoint`). После первой записи в массив добавляю ИД записи из таблицы (которую в последующей рекурсии буду проверять, что бы не возвращаться в эту запись, ну и использую для вывода результата), ну и после нее соответственно точку `$nextPoint` (которую в последующей рекурсии подам как `$point1`). Перед вызовом рекурсии проверяю, является ли следующая точка `$nextPoint` равна `$finishPoint`. Если так - возвращаю результирующий массив. Если нет - запускаю рекурсию. Я понимаю, что код можно и нужно оптимизировать, но пока результата нет - нету смысла и оптимизировать.

Код пока выглядит так:

```
try {
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=voyage", "root", "");
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}catch (PDOException $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM distances ORDER BY distance_km";
$st = $dbh->query($query);
$res = $st->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

function getRoute($point1 = false, $point2 = false, $arr)
{
    if ((!$point1 || !$point2) || ($point1 == $point2) || !$arr)
        return false;
    $tableArray = $arr;
    static $result = array();
    static $finishPoint = "";
    $nextPoint = "";

    foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
        if (array_search($value['id'], $result)) //Если в массиве уже есть ИД записи, тогда крутим дальше. Так исключаем все предыдущие точки, с которых пришли
            continue;
        if (!$result) { //Точку входа №2 $point2 проверяю только на первой итерации, потому что во всех следующих ставлю туда имя следующей точки для поиска
            if ($point2 == $value['city_1']) {
                $finishPoint = $point1; // Если точка $point1 начало, значит $point2 - конец
                $result[] = $nextPoint;
                $result[] = $value['city_1'];
                $result['id'.$value['id']] = $value['id'];
                $result[] = $nextPoint;
            }
            if ($point2 == $value['city_2']) {
                $finishPoint = $point1;
                $nextPoint = $value['city_1'];
                $result[] = $value['city_2'];
                $result['id'.$value['id']] = $value['id'];
                $result[] = $nextPoint;
            }
        }

        if ($point1 == $value['city_1']) {
            $nextPoint = $value['city_2'];
            if($result){
                $result['id'.$value['id']] = $value['id'];
                $result[] = $value['city_1'];
            }else{
                $result[] = $value['city_1'];
                $result['id'.$value['id']] = $value['id'];
                $result[] = $nextPoint;
            }
        }
        if ($point1 == $value['city_2']) {
            $nextPoint = $value['city_1'];
            if($result){
                $result['id'.$value['id']] = $value['id'];
                $result[] = $nextPoint;
            }else{
                $result[] = $value['city_2'];
                $result['id'.$value['id']] = $value['id'];
                $result[] = $nextPoint;
            }
        }
        if(!$finishPoint)
            $finishPoint = $point2;

        if ($nextPoint == $finishPoint)
            return $result;
        getRoute($nextPoint, $finishPoint, $tableArray);
    }
    return $result;
}


echo "<pre>";
print_r(getRoute('A', 'F', $res));
echo "</pre>";
```

Почему-то получается вот так:

```
Array
(
    [0] => A
    [id1] => 1
    [1] => B
    [id4] => 4
    [2] => B
    [id2] => 2
    [3] => A
    [id5] => 5
    [4] => C
    [id7] => 7
    [5] => D
    [id6] => 6
    [6] => C
    [id8] => 8
    [7] => E
    [id3] => 3
    [8] => A
)
```

Хотя должно быть так:

```
Array
(
    [0] => A
    [id1] => 1
    [1] => B
    [id4] => 4
    [2] => F
)
```

П.С. Для удобства, исходящий массив из таблицы БД выглядит так:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [city_1] => C
            [city_2] => D
            [distance_km] => 60
            [time_mins] => 20
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [city_1] => A
            [city_2] => B
            [distance_km] => 80
            [time_mins] => 40
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 8
            [city_1] => E
            [city_2] => F
            [distance_km] => 80
            [time_mins] => 40
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [city_1] => A
            [city_2] => C
            [distance_km] => 110
            [time_mins] => 55
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 7
            [city_1] => D
            [city_2] => F
            [distance_km] => 192
            [time_mins] => 110
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [id] => 6
            [city_1] => C
            [city_2] => E
            [distance_km] => 205
            [time_mins] => 80
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [city_1] => A
            [city_2] => E
            [distance_km] => 330
            [time_mins] => 240
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [city_1] => B
            [city_2] => F
            [distance_km] => 340
            [time_mins] => 230
        )

)
```