# Алгоритм Дейкстры для поиска пути в дереве с циклами

Tags: java, алгоритм, поиск, дерево

Кто подскажет как правильно должен работать алгоритм Дейкстры при обходе дерева с циклами. Т.е. есть дерево которое отражает лабиринт, в нем есть циклы, необходимо найти кратчайший путь от одной произвольной вершины до другой. Преобразовать дерево в матрицу смежности нельзя.
К примеру, дерево выглядит так, как на картинке. Выходит что веса всех ребер равны 1. Как правильно должен себя вести алгоритм когда определяет метку ячейки начиная с выделенной зеленым, должен ли он ее отметить как посещенную после того, как произойдет релаксация ребер ее соседей, если да, то не закончится ли выполнение алгоритма, после того как он перейдет из зеленой вершины в желтую, т.к. все ее соседи будут отмечены как посещенные. Возможно я очень путано задаю вопрос, если что поправьте. Спасибо!
з.ы. код пишу на java если будут примеры.
[image: дерево]

Comment: что за картинка?

Comment: для понимания структуры, что я создал ). вот пытаюсь ссылкой загрузить тоже не выходит, сейчас что-то придумаю. при попытке вставить изображение в сообщение/вопрос появляется форма с загрузкой, после загрузки изображения, я его вижу но как его вставить в вопрос не понимаю, нет доступных действий кроме отменить..

Comment: все с изображением получилось, теперь жду помощи )

Comment: Вот тут я как то писал дейкстру http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/482044/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-php-%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA-%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%88%D1%80%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B0/482120#482120  Что у вас значит "_перейду из зеленой в желтую_" дейкстра не предполагает перехода от одной вершины к другой. вы делаете расчет веса из одной вершины, помечаете ее как обработанную и начинаете работать с любой еще не обработанной

Comment: @Mike вот кусок текста с педевикии "Второй шаг. Шаг алгоритма повторяется. Снова находим «ближайшую» из непосещённых вершин. Это вершина 2 с меткой 7." т.о. я понимаю в алгоритме есть система перехода от одной вершины к другой по наименьшему значению ребра от текущей вершины. может я не верно трактую алгоритм и в этом моя проблема, тогда возникает вопрос если не последовательно брать вершины дерева, то для понимания того остались ли еще не посещенные нужно каждый раз просматривать дерево полностью

Comment: в дополнение вот еще кусок текста с хабра "..отмечаем 5-ю вершину как посещенную и выбираем следующую вершину, которая имеет минимальную метку. Повторяем все перечисленные выше действия до тех пор, пока есть непосещенные вершины."

Comment: Да, мы просматриваем весь список вершин. Кстати, после того как обследовали очередную вершину вполне может оказаться что с минимальной меткой у нас окажется не одна из ее соседей, а какая то из вершин которые упоминались до этого. Мы же берем вершину с минимальной меткой, а не с минимальным ребром до нее из текущей вершины. Метка вершины - это как раз то число которое мы расчитываем для каждой из них. Т.е. стоимость прохода в нее из изначальной вершины

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Небольшая путаница в терминах теории графов. Не бывает "дерева с циклами", потому что по определению, дерево - это связный ациклический (то есть без циклов) граф.

Дейкстра, хоть на дереве, хоть на графе будет работать одинаково. Главное условие, чтобы веса всех дуг (или ребер в случае отсутствия ориентации) были неотрицательные, больше или равны нулю. 
Реализацию Дейкстры на Java можно посмотреть тут http://cybern.ru/algoritm-dejkstry-realizaciya-na-java.html

При этом, если веса всех ребер равны 1, то кратчайший путь от одной произвольной вершины до другой можно найти обычным поиском в ширину. Это даже будет асимптотически быстрее на порядок, так Дейсктра работает за квадрат кол-ва вершин в дереве или графе, а поиск в ширину на O(N).

Про поиск в ширину можно почитать тут: http://cybern.ru/obxod-v-shirinu.html

В конце статьи есть ссылки по реализации обхода в ширину на Java, С++ и Python

Comment: Добавьте в ответ минимальный необходимый пример решения (информацию по ссылке могут удалить и ответ потеряет ценность).

Answer (score 3):

Насколько я понимаю, алгоритм Дейкстры применим к графу с циклами, если в графе нету циклов *отрицательного* веса (то есть, отрицательной суммарной длины).

С другой стороны, если в графе есть цикл отрицательного веса (находящийся по пути из исходной к целевой вершине), задача поиска минимального пути не имеет смысла, так как вес пути, ведущего через цикл, можно сделать как угодно маленьким, «докрутив» кругов по циклу.

---

Ситуации, как у вас на рисунке, при пробеге алгоритма не произойдёт. Если алгоритм сначала выберет белую тройку как вершину с минимальным весом, он проставит четвёрку, и отметит белую тройку посещённой. Затем он выберет в качестве минимального непосещённого элемента жёлтую тройку, и запишет в зелёную вершину 4.

Comment: нет, отрицательных длин нет, я просто не могу понять как мне написать правильно код под такой алгоритм, что он должен делать, когда попадает в ситуацию что я описал выше, может я не верно понимаю то, как он обходит дерево

Comment: @Bender: Обновил ответ.

Comment: дело вот в чем:

Comment: если я правильно понимаю,возникнет такая ситуация: когда вершиной будет белая 2-ка, у двух ее соседних вершин появится метка 3, т.к. метки равны выбирается произвольная следующая вершина, текущая отметится как посещенная. выполнение перейдет к белой 3-ке - из нее единственная не посещенная вершина будет та, что станет белой 4-кой и белая 3-ка отметится как посещенная таком образом дойдет до зеленой 5-и, и вот тут выходит что у нее есть 2 соседа 3 и 6, пятерка отметится посещенной и выполнение перейдет на тройку, у которой окажется что нет не посещенных соседей и алгоритм завершится,разве нет?

Comment: @Bender: Белая тройка даст белую четвёрку. На следующем шагу будет выбрана жёлтая тройка, а не белая четвёрка (т. к. 3 < 4), она пропишет в зелёной вершине 4. Затем, например, будет выбрана белая 4-ка, она предоставит путь длины 5 к зелёной вершине, но поскольку к этой вершине уже есть путь длины 4, то этот путь длины 5 отбросится.