# Как правильно написать запрос в базу данных?

Tags: php, mysql

Дана форма, где я выбираю станцию(начало) и станцию(конец), и он должен выдать все остановки которые в таблице posmi, только вместо id должно быть название станции

Есть таблица stac со следующими ячейками

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

есть таблица posmi

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И простая форма

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И когда я выбираю например Tornakalns и Zasulauks мне выводило следующее:

```
2 Tornakalns - Zasulauks
3 Zasulauks - Tornakalns
```

Вот мой недозапрос:

```
select
          s.stacija, p.id, p.sakstacid, p.beigstacid
          from
          posmi as p
          right join
          stac as s
          on
          p.sakstacid = s.id
          RIGHT JOIN
          stac as st
          ON
          p.beigstacid=st.id
          where
          p.sakstacid  in ("'.$_POST['from_place'].'", "'.$_POST['for_place'].'") and
          p.beigstacid  in ("'.$_POST['for_place'].'", "'.$_POST['from_place'].'")
```

Comment: Что дано и что нужно получить? Например. дана станция(?), получить список соседних станций?

Comment: Дана форма, где я выбираю станцию(начало) и станцию(конец), и он должен выдать все остановки которые в таблице posmi, только вместо id должно быть название станции

Comment: Все остановки между станциями? Остановки тоже станции? Тут простым запросом не получится. Нужен рекурсивный. Это думать надо. Посмотрите в гугле тему recursive cte. А может и это не поможет. Ведь путь заранее неизвестен, это надо все маршруты перебирать. Загрузить граф остановок в память и там по теории графов прокладывать путь из A в B

Comment: Спасибо за ответ ) боюсь я еще с простыми запросами толком не разобрался, разбираться с рекурсивными явно рановато )

Comment: Посмотрите, я как раз искал маршрут для одного ответа и как раз на MySQL. А нормальных рекурсивных запросов, которые сильно упростили бы задачу в MySQL нет. http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/482044/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-php-%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA-%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%88%D1%80%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B0/482120#482120