# Определить всех потомков для данного корня

Tags: php, дерево

Есть таблица категорий со следующей вполне стандартной и известной структурой: |id|parent_id|name|...| . Когда-то еще давно нашел где-то в сети очень хорошую функцию по формированию дерева категорий с любым уровнем вложенности:

```
public function mapTree($dataset)
{
    $tree = [];

    foreach ($dataset as $id=>&$node) {
        if (!$node['parent_id']) {
            $tree[$id] = &$node;
        } else {
            $dataset[$node['parent_id']]['childs'][$id] = &$node;
        }
    }

    return $tree;
}
```

Задача заключается вот в чем: нужно сформировать из БД структурированное дерево таким образом:

- Категория 1 (корень)

  - Название категории 1
  - Одномерный массив всех потомков категории 1 с учетом всех вложенностей
- Категория 2 (корень)

  - Название категории 2
  - Одномерный массив всех потомков категории 2 с учетом всех вложенностей
- ... и так далее

Сложность заключается в том, что в базе данных, скажем, у "Категории 1" (являющейся корнем с parent_id=0) может быть сколько угодно потомков, а у этих потомков в свою очередь - свои потомки, и т.д. - короче говоря, древовидная структура с неизвестным уровнем вложенности. Таким образом, нужно, чтобы в результате на выходе был массив приведенной выше структуры.

Вопрос: можно ли как-то модифицировать приведенную мною функцию, или как вообще это реализовать?

P.S: очень хотелось бы для себя разобраться с этой темой на каких-то простых примерах, чтобы наверняка "дошло", а также если вам не составит труда - не могли бы вы продемонстрировать на примере как наоборот можно получить список всех предков для текущей категории (очень может пригодится для таких же новичков как я - например, при формировании хлебных крошек на сайте).

Comment: Посмотрите, недавно что то подобное было, может от сюда поймете http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/481945/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B2-php/481979#481979

Comment: Увы, сходства с моей задачей не увидел.

Comment: там то же вложенный массив и то же возвращается массив схожей структуры и функция вызывает саму себя - т.е. обеспечивает рекурсию. вот и вам надо вставить вызов самой себя куда то. но это надо делать не "в общем", а видя конкретно ваши данные и что из них  надо получить

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$input=array(  // Исходный массив (как в базе)
              array("id"=>2, "parent_id"=>1, "name"=>"Category 1"),
              array("id"=>4, "parent_id"=>2, "name"=>"Category 1.1"),
              array("id"=>8, "parent_id"=>4, "name"=>"Category 1.1.1"),
              array("id"=>5, "parent_id"=>2, "name"=>"Category 1.2"),
              array("id"=>3, "parent_id"=>1, "name"=>"Category 2"),
              array("id"=>6, "parent_id"=>3, "name"=>"Category 2.1"),
              array("id"=>7, "parent_id"=>3, "name"=>"Category 2.2"),
              array("id"=>9, "parent_id"=>3, "name"=>"Category 2.3"),
              array("id"=>1, "parent_id"=>0, "name"=>"root element 1"),
              array("id"=>10, "parent_id"=>0, "name"=>"root element 2")
           );

$result=array();
foreach ($input as &$node) { // Строим предварительный массив с индексами по parent_id
 if(!$node['parent_id']) { // Это корневой элемент - перенести только имя
   $result[$node['id']]['name']=$node['name'];
  } else { // Добавить элемент в массив с ключом parent_id
   $result[$node['parent_id']][]=&$node;
  }
}
var_dump($result); // Печать предварительного массива
foreach ($result as $k=>&$node) { // Для всех корневых элементов строим ветви
 if(array_key_exists('name',$node)) BuildTree($result,$node);
}
var_dump($result); // Печать дерева

function BuildTree(&$result,&$root) // Функция перестройки ветви
{ // Параметры - весь массив и текущая ветвь
 foreach ($root as $k=>&$node) {
   if(!is_array($node)) continue;
   if(isset($result[$node['id']])) {          // Если есть элементы с parent_id=текущий id
     BuildTree($result,$result[$node['id']]); // Строим дерево для вложенных элементов
     $root[$k][]=$result[$node['id']];        // переносим вложенную ветвь из начального массива на ее место
     unset($result[$node['id']]);             // Удаляем ветвь с изначального места
    }
  }
}
?>
```

Алгоритм состоит их двух стадий. На первой исходный массив переносится в рабочий. При этом все не корневые элементы выносятся в подмассивы с ключами по parent_id, таким образом зная id ветви можно мгновенно найти в этом массиве всех ее непосредственных детей. Все что остается на второй этап - это перенести детей во вложенные массивы к родителям. Эта часть рекурсивная, если у текущего проверяемого элемента есть дети, их записи переносятся с индексированных позиций в общем массиве на их места в родительском (текущем) элементе.

А для поиска всех родительских элементов надо построить массив с ключами id-элемента, после этого берем parent_id по нему идем в такой массив берем элемент - это родитель, если у него есть то же parent_id - то идем по нему и получаем дедушку и т.п.

Answer (score 0):

Эта магия называется [**Рекурсия**](https://www.google.com.ua/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=php%20%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE). Прошу простить за краткость ответа, ибо здесь нечего много расписывать.

Comment: Да, я знаю. Но, к сожалению её понимание далеко от меня, как бы я этого не хотел - потому и задал здесь вопрос.

Comment: Все элементарно просто, функция вызывает саму себя!

Comment: Ваша функция, если вложенности больше нет, т.е. мы добрались до корня или до листа, смотря с какой стороны заходить - вернуть значение для данного листа. А если есть вложенность - то вызвать сама себя для этой ветви и то что она вернет добавить в массив

Comment: Ребята, ну если вы владеете этой "магией" - почему бы ей не поделиться?

Comment: @pioneer А вы думаете по вашему вопросу понятно что именно вы хотите получить ? Я например вообще не могу понять что делает та функция что вы привели. Вижу что она как то перестраивает дерево которое ей на вход подали. Но исходная и требуемая структура массива в вопросе не приведены. А вы еще хотите из какой то эфимерной базы данных это выбрать. А многие современные СУБД между прочим могут сами дерево построить (кроме mysql) так что с каждой базой для построения дерева надо по разному работать

Comment: @Mike, СУБД с которой я работаю - как раз-таки MySQL. Функция, которую я привел - формирует дерево (массив) любого уровня вложенности. Исходная структура дерева - одномерный массив категорий (поля я привел в начале сообщения), требуемая структура - массив, каждый из элементов которого в свою очередь тоже является массивом из 2 элементов: 1 - название корня, 2 - одномерный массив всех его потомков на всех уровнях.

Comment: @pioneer Вы похоже когда "нашли хорошую функцию" взяли только 1 функцию из какого то более большого набора. Я наконец понял, что она делает, она делает индексированный по родителям массив, что бы потом по нему было легче строить дерево. почему же вы не взяли все

Answer (score 0):

Рекурсия это конечно хорошо, но дабы не возникало трудностей в работе с деревьями и манипуляциях с ними - лучше использовать **Nested Sets** (Вложенные множества).
Этот подход позволяет работать прозрачно с деревьями, без рекурсий.
Единственный минус - тяжелые манипуляции с деревом, но чтение одним запросом хоть потомков, хоть все корни и т.д. Да и чтение требуется, как правило, чаще, чем манипуляции.
Но в любом случае, если серьёзно строить реальные проекты - лучше для хранения деревьев не найти.
Вот [отличная статья](http://www.getinfo.ru/article610.html)

Comment: Я боюсь для реальных проектов это слишком напряжно будет. При добавлении элемента пересчет всех ключей в одном из поддеревьев... Интересно как оно будет работать на небольшом дереве, скажем в 100к записей