# Правильная рекурсия?

Tags: php, рекурсия

Всем привет!
Есть база данных

| id | parent_id | name | alias |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | одежда | odegda |
| 2 | 1 | мужская | mugskay |
| 3 | 2 | брюки мужские | bruki |
| 3 | 1 | женская | genskay |
| 4 | 3 | брюки женские | брюки |

Подскажите пжл, как сделать правильно рекурсию и собрать для каждой категории полный url, например:
odegda
odegda/mugskay
odegda/mugskay/bruki
odegda/genskay
odegda/genskay/bruki

И каким методом лучше.

1. от начала parent_id = 0 (тут же как-то надо применить еще ссылку)
   как это все записать первым способом?
2. с конца категорий от bruki

```
foreach ($categories as $cat) {

    $srt = $cat->alias; // записываем bridzhi
    $item = $categories->firstWhere('id', $cat->parent_id); // находим подкатегорию у bridzhi

    while ( !empty($item) ) { //если у bridzhi есть подкатегория
        $srt = $item->alias. '/' .$srt; // записываем mugskay/bridzhi
        $item = $categories->firstWhere('id', $item->parent_id); // находим подкатегорию у bridzhi mugskay
    }
    $cat->url = $srt; // odegda/mugskay/bridzhi

}
```

3. видел что некоторые не используют колонку parent_id, место нее другая и в нее записываются id шники - #1#19#43#121. Как думаете по поводу этого способа?

Comment: Если построить надо для всех, то поскольку мы заранее не знаем что bruki - это последняя категория, да еще и не одна, то начинать надо, разумеется, сверху. а рекурсия самая обычная, тут нету правильной или неправильной - она всегда одинаковая. Если мы знаем ид категории и нам надо построить для нее путь, то рекурсия не нужна, достаточно цикла

Comment: @Ипатьев спасибо за ответ! А быстрее будет если применить 1й вариант? или одинаково

Comment: Быстрее чем что?

Comment: @Ипатьев . При втором варианте мне каждую категорию надо пройти циклом while, т.е очень много циклов. При первом варианте мне кажется что циклов будет меньше, правильно? т.е где мы берем сначала самые первые категории parent_id = 0 и от них начинаем

Comment: я вообще не понимаю, где тут второй вариант. откуда вы знаете, с какой категории начинать цикл while?

Comment: Быстрее всего будет получить одним запросом всю таблицу в массив, а потом уже из него строить дерево, https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/482852/179379

Comment: $categories->where('parent_id', 0) выбираю все первые категории, прохожу в цикле добавляю первый URL и для каждой последующей. Или так нельзя?

Comment: можно. как угодно можно.

Comment: Я одного не понимаю - как вы заранее узнали, что bridzhi - это конечная категория, и у неё точно нет подкатегорий, скажем, khaki и linen

Comment: если я правильно понял 1я категория//2я//3я//bridzhi//5я. Как я понял что после bridzhi нет категорий (5я). так я же собираю URL для каждой категории. для 5й категории нужно собирать уже другой URL))) Я тут веду сбор url от 4й категории к 1й

Comment: понятно. $categories - это результат *ещё одного* запроса в БД. Ну тогда да, это какой-то чудовищно неоптимальный код, количество запросов при котором значительно превышает общее количество категорий

Comment: #1#19#43#121 называется materialized path. Крутая штука, но в вашем случае особо не поможет. Если только не писать в него собственно искомый путь. тогда все пути будут получаться одним запросом. А если еще и сделать order by path, то и сразу в формате дерева